# Linting error on creating material icon clickable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to create material icon clickable however getting linting error 
**Visible, non-interactive elements should not have mouse or keyboard event listeners jsx-a11y/no-static-element-interactions**

Below is the syntax I am using

```
<i className="material-icons control-arrow" onClick={this.sideNav} >arrow_back</i>
```

Please suggest me how can I achieve this without changing the element.

Comment: would that same error apply to a span?

Comment: This is a just linting error, correct? It should still work... Wrap `<i>` in a `<div>` if you're really concerned.

Comment: @promisified Yes same error for span as well.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a role, for example `button`:

```
<i
  className="material-icons control-arrow"
  onClick={this.sideNav}
  role="button">
    arrow_back
</i>
```

more info in the [jsx-a11y/no-static-element-interactions docs](https://github.com/evcohen/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/master/docs/rules/no-static-element-interactions.md)